# "Your communities" section showing me to only have 1 rep on certain SE site, but I do have 101 rep on the site

Tags: bug, reputation

In the `Your Communities` list in the StackExchange menu I have found that it thinks that I only have `1` rep on the Hardware Recommendations SE site:

[image: Hardware Recommendations showing to have only 1 rep incorrectly]

However when going to the site it shows that I have `101` reputation on the actual site, though in the menu the `1` remains. Other sites where I have `101` (because of the association bonus) are showing correctly in the menu so it's not just cancelling out the association bonus for all of them or something.

So this is most strange and I thought worth reporting. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 and Firefox 48 if it helps.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rwtId.png